# if statements not working correctly [C++]

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, operator-keyword

I am writing code to check if a sentence is a palindrome. I feel like my logic is correct, but the if statements for check the reverse of the string do not seem to be working. I have tried many solutions online but still nothing. Every string is seen as not a palindrome. I feel the error is at (sentence == reverse):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {

while (true) {
  string sentence;
  string reverse = "";

  cout << "Enter a sentence below to check (-1 to end):" << endl;
  getline(cin, sentence);

  if (sentence == "q") {
    break;
  }

  for (int i = sentence.length(); i >= 0; i-- ) {
    reverse += sentence[i];
  }

  cout << sentence << " reversed is: " << "[" << reverse << "]" << endl;

  if (sentence == reverse) {
      cout << sentence << " is a palindrome" << endl;
  } else {
    cout << sentence << " is not a palindrome" << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;
}

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably using String::compare http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: what is printed out when you print out the sentence and its reverse?

Also you are going to thoroughly confuse your users by requiring -1 to end but actually testing for q

Comment: @Dougie `compare` is for ordering, `==` is for equality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not the `if`. It's this part:

```
for (int i = sentence.length(); i >= 0; i--) {
        reverse += sentence[i];
}
```

`i = sentence.length()` is wrong, you have to start at `i = sentence.length()-1`. Otherwise it seems to add a whitespace character to the string, resulting in the wrong result. That loop should be:

```
for (int i = sentence.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverse += sentence[i];
}
```

Note that according [to the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at):

> Returns a reference to the character at specified location pos. No
>   bounds checking is performed. If pos > size(), the behavior is
>   undefined.

So the added whitespace isn't guaranteed, anything can happen. For a safer version check out the [at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) function, this one will throw an exception if the position is invalid instead of silently causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Maybe beginners should prefer `sentence.at(i)` as an alternative to `sentence[i]` so that bounds checking is performed.

Comment: Thanks! Great little explanation. Works now

Comment: Another valid form for the loop is `for (int i = sentence.length(); i > 0; i--) reverse += sentence[i-1];` I'd go with your formulation for this case, but if the loop index is unsigned, `i >= 0` is always true and you end up with an infinite loop. You should have both forms in your toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

The end of a string is it's `length - 1`, so use this instead:

```
for (int i = sentence.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

replace your for loop with this

```
for (int i = sentence.length()-1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
```